# Outputting multiple messages in the same message box?

Tags: java

This code technically works but now I need to output it in a message box. I tried putting a message box in front of each thing it has to display but that outputs it on multiple different message boxes. How can I make it so the program outputs it into one message box? Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CozaLozatest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 int result2=0;
String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input an interger");
 int result = Integer.parseInt(n);

for (int i=0; i<result; i++){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ");
        ++result2;
    if (result2 % 11 == 0)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ");

     if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {    
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CozaLozaWoza");} 

 else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CozaLoza");

  } else if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LozaWoza");

  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Loza");

  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Coza");

    } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Woza");




  } else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," "+i);

 }
}

    }
}
```

Also here is my code that works without the output boxes

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CozaLozaFinished
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   int result2=0;
    String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input an interger");
     int result = Integer.parseInt(n);

for (int i=0; i<result; i++){

 System.out.print(" ");
        ++result2;
    if (result2 % 11 == 0)
      System.out.println();

     if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {    
       System.out.print("CozaLozaWoza");} 

 else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.print("CozaLoza");

  } else if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
      System.out.print("LozaWoza");

  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
      System.out.print("Loza");

  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.print("Coza");

    } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
    System.out.print("Woza");




  } else {
    System.out.print(" "+i);

  }
}

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one Logan. Have you tried building a string inside the for loop, and then once the loop has exited, you can have a single call to the messagebox with the string you built. ps \n for a new line.

Comment: Before asking new questions, you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to your previous ones, or people won't want to answer you (like me).

Comment: Sorry :( I'm new here so I did not really know about that. I went back and accepted the answer you gave me. Again sorry about that won't happen again.

Comment: You should [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) then. Also, if there are other questions you asked and someone posted the right answer for you, then go accept those too. People are putting time into reading your code, finding the problem, coming up with a solution and explaining it to you.

Comment: Do you want all the iterations' results to be in one message box or one message box for each iteration?

Comment: I need them to be in one box. I think I can do this if I can somehow save all the text to one string, which I am trying to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wil want to use a `StringBuilder`. `append` to it all the text instead of printing to the console and at the end convert it to a `String` and display it:

```
public class CozaLozatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int result2 = 0;
        String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input an interger");
        int result = Integer.parseInt(n);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
            ++result2;
            if (result2 % 11 == 0)
                sb.append("\n");
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
                sb.append("CozaLozaWoza");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                sb.append("CozaLoza");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
                sb.append("LozaWoza");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                sb.append("Loza");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                sb.append("Coza");
            } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
                sb.append("Woza");
            } else {
                sb.append(" " + i);
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
    }
}
```